# bug in frankenstein?

Tags: packages, include, bugs

I cannot get `includedocskip` in the `newclude` package to work.  As far as I can tell, it requires the `allocate` option, but this option loads `allocate.sto`, which uses an `InitWheel` command that has not been defined.  As an example, create these two files and try to compile the first.

```
%file: temp.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[allocate]{newclude}
\begin{document} 
\includedocskip{temp99.tex} 
\end{document}

%file: temp99.tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Test.
\end{document}
```

Comment: the command is defined further down `allocate.sto`  the top of the file does say `This code has not been well tested yet.....`

Comment: And the testing seems to have been going on for almost 19 years…

Comment: The `frankenstein` bundle is essentially abandonware.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The old `includex` package at least more at less worked.  The `newclude` package does not seem to work at all for the inclusions of documents whose headers should be skipped.  
How should I report this?

Comment: @Alan as egreg says in his answer, you could try mailing the author but probably you'd need to fix yourself and post an update to ctan, or you could use standalone or includex, but really I would never use any of these for this use case , they are all fragile and likely to have conflicts with other packages, it is much easier to simply put the body of` `temp99.tex` into `temp99-body.tex` and then use `\input{temp99-body}` in both `temp.tex` and `temp99.tex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `frankenstein` bundle has been silent for about 17 years. I don't think that filing a bug report can be of any consequence.

I think you can switch to `standalone`, for the purpose you have.

```
% file temp.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document} 
\includestandalone{temp99} 
\end{document}

%file: temp99.tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Test.
\end{document}
```